# simultaneous runs of two JS webworkers: one gets stuck

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, multithreading, web-worker

I'm working on a closed system web application to aid companies in their everyday online commerce chores. That means on the one hand that it won't be open to the public, on the other: it will have to deal with large amounts of data while maintaining a fluent work experience.

This is why I turned to web workers in JS to run all sorts of database access and data loading in the background.
My understanding is, that not only the main UI/main JS remains uninterrupted but also the different web workers run without hindering each other.

I now have the following setup:

**mainJS**: function statusCheck which runs on pageload:

```
function statusCheck() {
    if(typeof(w__statusCheck) == "undefined") {
        var w__statusCheck = new Worker("...statusCheck.js");
        w__statusCheck.postMessage("go");
        w__statusCheck.onmessage = function(e) {
            var message = JSON.parse(e.data);
            if(message.text!=undefined) displayMessage(message.text);
        }
}
```

**statusCheck.js** which is the worker simply goes like this:

```
function checkStatus() {
        console.log("statusCheck started");
        // I will leave standard parts out:
            // creating and testing the ajax variable against different browsers

        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
                self.postMessage(ajaxRequest.responseText);

                var timer;
                timer = self.setTimeout(function(){
                    checkStatus();
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "...worker_statusCheck.php", true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
    }

    this.onmessage = function(e){
        checkStatus();
    };
```

As you can see, this restarts itself every second (for now). The intervall might be longer in production.
worker_statusCheck.php simply gets different things from the database and knits them into a JSON object which gives me the system status.

This works beautifully.

Now I have another worker which is supposed to get initiated by a click on a link to effectively call some php to perform actions:
**mainJS** loadWorker

```
function loadWorker(url="") {
    console.log("loadWorker started");

    if(url!="") {
        var uniqueID = "XXX" // creating a random ID based on timestamp and Math.random()

    if(typeof(window[uniqueID]) == "undefined") {
        var variables = { ajaxURL: url };
        window[uniqueID] = new Worker("....loadWorker.js");
        window[uniqueID].postMessage(JSON.stringify(variables));
        window[uniqueID].onmessage = function(e) {
            var message = JSON.parse(e.data);
            if(message["success"]!=undefined) {
                variables["close"] = "yes";
                window[uniqueID].postMessage(JSON.stringify(variables));
            }
        }
}
```

With every click on a certain link this gets called, creates a uniquely named worker, runs it, receives the data and tells the worker to `close()`.

The php again does its thing and writes a progress update in the DB after each step of the lengthy procedure. These progress updates I fetch from the DB with the above repeating statusCheck.

Now, I can see the entries in the DB with timestamp, so I know they get written each at their time.
So, both workers do their job and run reliably. But I have noticed, that whenever I initiate the manual (randomly named) worker the statusCheck actually stops performing. It just gets stuck... I was able to confirm this with console output from both workers. So it's not the main JS that seems stuck, but the statusCheck actually pauses... and resumes when loadWorker is done.

Am I missing something fundamental here? Any insight would be appreciated since I'm new to this concept of web workers.

Thanx :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright.. I figured it out:
I was looking in all the wrong places. Turns out, I had initialized my php session in all the php scripts which are called by the workers. And my two parallel workers both called one. So the session file was locked by the first php script and the second had to wait until it was back open again. It was not the workers or the JS being hindered, it was the php.

I now took out the session initialization from my statusCheck.php and it works like a charm. I will keep it in those others that handle the user input responses because there it actually makes sense: user clicks on button "compile data XY" which is run by the worker and takes a while. Impatient as he is he already clicks the next button "show this data"... and due to the locked session file I have sort of a neat queue for those actions. :)

I still will take above recommendations to heart and see to it to improve my code. :)

Comment: Is that so? How? I only see JS and document messages. No php output. Also, there wasn't an error anywhere. Just a delay. Maybe I'm not as enlightened as you are, so maybe you can help me out here...

Comment: If you look into the console, you will see that one of the requests is loading and did not receive any data. That would you give enough hint to know that the problem is in the communication with the server and you could easily check that it's not related to web workers. You would still need to figure out what the problem is, but at least you wouldn't post a question that cannot be ever answered without a crystal ball. Also note that saying "*Maybe I'm not as enlightened as you are*" is often used as a rude sarcasm so it's better to avoid it on the internet to avoid heated debates.

Comment: You're right. This is how I figured it out at last.. I did have my console.logs in mind when asking the question. In fact I mentioned them confirming my problem. What I don't understand is how my answer doesn't solve the original question and got a downvote. The console doesn't tell me the exact problem but an effect of it. Which needed to be explained. And with not enough experience in these matters I resorted to asking here. The fact that I came up with a solution myself should be reason to upvote - if anything.
Still: Thanks for your efforts and the valuable hints on making my code better.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks resources to truly figure out what exactly goes wrong. I can concur that [two web workers can operate at the same time](https://jsfiddle.net/7484nhhq/), even with synchronous operations. I tested this for both `for` loops and sync XHR requests.

There are multiple things I would recommend though.

First - **unless you're processing the data with some CPU heavy algorithm, web workers are waste of time.** XHR requests do not block main thread (unless you explicitly ask them to).

1. In `statusCheck()` you declare `var w__statusCheck` which means a local variable. Therefore it will always be null as seen from outer scope. It might get garbage-collected once no code is running in the worker.
2. Do not use `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange`. Use `onload` and `onerror`.
3. Random unique ID's for variables are almost always wrong. If you need to store the worker refference at all, either give it a reasonable name (eg. the url it's supposed to load) or use incremental id.
4. Do **NOT** `stringify` data that you post to web worker. It's already done for you by the browser, possibly in more optimal manner. Converting the data to something is a single most common stupid thing people do with web workers.

Also when posting question, at least make sure the code makes some sense. In your post curly braces do not match.

Comment: First of all: thanks for the pointers! I will look into them, try them out and see where it leads.

As for using web workers at all or not... the first version of the app is in use for a few years now and after the initial idea more and more features came into play. By now there are really heavy and lengthy calculations running.

As to the missing braces: I copied from working code and stripped out irrelevant parts in the editor here.. I guess I got one too many..

Okay.. I will try everything and post results here. Have a great weekend!!

Comment: meant to ask about the random ID.. Is there a logical reason why they might be almost always wrong? My goal was to make them all unique so nothing interfers. And since they `close()` right after execution anyway and don't need to be known in any other context...
I think var names can not have special chars?! So I create names like this: `"WorkerID_"+random_number+now()`

Comment: @AurelEngleEngelmann And since when exactly does random number mean *different number every time*? I see no logical to use random numbers instead of increment (eg. 0, 1, 2, 3), which is also easier to debug since it gives you information about order of creation. The way you create random number looks like you think that the more random stuff you mesh together the better, but that's not true. And yeah, variable names can not have special characters. But object properties can. This is valid: `var dd = {"☺":"smiley"}` And so is this: `window["☺"] = "smiley"`

Comment: I didn't know about the special chars. :) 

.... I know Math.random() doesn't reliably produce a _different_ result all the time.. but since this function runs on mouse click by user I combined the random number with now() timestamp. This way I'm thinking I will always actually have a different value - even in those cases when Math.random() does give the same number or even if the OS triggers a double click in the same instance.. which is something that happened to me a while back due to a faulty mouse.

Anyway.. thanks for the insight, will try on monday and post results :)